# Do any American politicians support banning pet euthanasia?

Tags: united-states, law, ethics

Euthanasia is the act of ending someone's life in order to relieve them of pain.  It is illegal in many jurisdictions, and numerous American politicians, especially Republicans, support keeping it illegal where it's illegal, and banning it where it is legal.

But pets are often euthanized as well.  So my question is, are there any American politicians who support banning pet euthanasia?

Comment: This is in my view too broad as applied to all politicians everywhere in the world (without even a clear boundary regarding who is a politician or what constitutes support). Given that there are millions of politicians in the world, I imagine that someone, somewhere does, at least in personal belief, but this question should be narrowed in some way for it to be useful.

Comment: @ohwilleke OK, I restricted things to America.

Comment: Animal slaughter isn't banned in the US. Technically, there's nothing in the law that will stop an owner from killing his pet for food. So, animal rights activists have bigger issues to fix, before they get to pet euthanasia.

Comment: @defaultlocale I think there are animal cruelty laws that prevent you from killing your dog for fun.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, killing for no reason is probably illegal. Killing something for food is treated differently though, e.g. some people keep rabbits as pets, others farm them as livestock. I'm not sure what is the legal consensus around dogs, but Wikipedia [says that it is legal to eat dog meat in 43 states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_meat#United_States). In any case, I believe that people who care about pet euthanasia would care about farm animals as well.

Comment: Ironically, it would be a progressive politician who would push for this, if any.

Comment: One way to research: find animal rights or vegan organizations onlines and see how they "rate" various politicians and why. As far as I know, most animal rights (and probably vegan) organizations are ok with putting sick pets down (it's actually more humane than letting them suffer), but you might some extreme ones who believe otherwise. As a note, the Supreme Court ruled that sacrificing animals for religious purposes is Constitutionally protected.

Answer (score 1):

No, and never.  (At least not any elected ones that I've ever heard of.)

Comment: Ideally there'd be polls and scholarly historic meta-studies to support this *"No"*, but SFAIK, nobody's gone to the trouble, the Q. being a default state.  Sort of like asking if any US politicians support cars that run on milk instead of gasoline.

Answer (score 1):

No I'm fairly certain no politicians in the United States are calling for bans on euthanasia.

As the question mentions, right wing politicians do support a ban on euthanasia for people. A major reason for this comes from catholic social teaching that life should begin at conception and continue until natural death. This comes from the idea that: [(from a Vatican published document)](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/resources/life-and-family/euthanasia-and-assisted-suicide/vatican-document-on-euthanasia)

> Human life is the basis of all goods, and is the necessary source and
>   condition of every human activity and of all society. Most people
>   regard life as something sacred and hold that no one may dispose of it
>   at will, but believers see in life something greater, namely, a gift
>   of God's love, which they are called upon to preserve and make
>   fruitful.

Therefore

> Life is a gift of God, and on the other hand death is unavoidable; it
>   is necessary, therefore, that we, without in any way hastening the
>   hour of death, should be able to accept it with full responsibility
>   and dignity.

Meanwhile when the [Catechism of the Catholic Church](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c2a7.htm) talks about animals, it says

> 2417 God entrusted animals to the stewardship of those whom he created
>   in his own image. Hence it is legitimate to use animals for food and
>   clothing. They may be domesticated to help man in his work and
>   leisure. Medical and scientific experimentation on animals is a
>   morally acceptable practice if it remains within reasonable limits and
>   contributes to caring for or saving human lives.
>
> 2418 It is contrary to human dignity to cause animals to suffer or die
>   needlessly. It is likewise unworthy to spend money on them that should
>   as a priority go to the relief of human misery. One can love animals;
>   one should not direct to them the affection due only to persons.

So Catholics believe in being stewards of animals, but not elevating to the level of humans and treating their lives with the reverence due to human life. This distinction is fairly common on the American right. I think a telling statistic is from [a survey](https://www.livescience.com/14302-political-ideology-liberal-conservative-food-choices.html) that found "ten percent of liberals indicated they are vegetarians, compared with 3 percent of conservatives."

While it is difficult to prove a negative, I believe that this helps explain why some American political groups would support a ban on euthanasia for humans but none would support a ban on euthanasia for animals.